# Aws Moto redshift statements description assertions (Python)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, testing, boto3, moto

Considering an AWS lambda written in Python that uses boto3 as client to AWS Redshift service.

Considering the following example:

```py
import boto3
import moto


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    session = boto3.session.Session()

    redshift_data_service = session.client(
        service_name='redshift-data',
        region_name='a_region',
    )

    query_id = redshift_data_service.execute_statement(
        sql="insert into XYZ VALUES..."
    )

    while True: // With timeout
        job_state = redshift_data_service.describe_statement(Id=query_id)

        if job_state["Status"] == "FAILED"
            break
        ...

@moto.redshiftdata
def test_insert_sql_insert():
    
    # MOCK describe_statement invocations here

    lambda_handler(...)
    redshift_data_service = boto3.client("redshift-data", region_name='a_region')
    
    # Assert execute_statement
```

I had to use a loop to check the state of the insert statement and retrieve the error. As far as I understood, to retrieve the error I need to do pooling using `describe_statement` as described here -> https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/blob/master/src/SimpleReplay/helper/aws_service.py

Using Moto python dependency to mock `redshift-data` (similar to the example above), how can I give in advance data regarding describe statements?

Is there a way to mock all the describe_statement retrieved by execute_statement?
The idea is testing the variuos state of the desscribe function considering the description of the statement, when it's "STARTED", "FAILED" and "FINISHED"